# Multiple CodeIgniter applications routing issue

Tags: codeigniter

I have a routing question for CodeIgniter.

I have two applications sharing the system folder with the following folder structure

```
./admin
./admin/index.php
./admin/{stylesheets, scripts, images, etc}

./site
./site/index.php
./site/{stylesheets, scripts, images, etc}

./applications/admin
./applications/admin/{controllers, models, config, etc.}
./applications/site
./applications/site/{controllers, models, config, etc.}

./system
```

All is working ok, except that I can only access my site as domain.com/site/controller_name/method_name. How can I get rid of the site part?

Also, is there an easy way to share helpers and libraries between the applications? Besides putting them in system/helpers.

Thanks!

Comment: You basically do this with sub-domains, making the default `www.yoursite.com` and `yoursite.com` lead to `site` folder and make a sub-domain `admin.yoursite.com` that will point to your `admin` folder. Or another way would be to write an `.htaccess` if you're on Apache and put it to your web root folder. Regarding shared helpers and libraries, you can use `third party/packages` http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/loader.html or you can always simply `include()`.

Comment: @Vlakarados It's an .htaccess/$routes[] solution I was after, how should the htaccess rule look like?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your root folder's .htaccess to

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^$ site [L]
```